# Would particles in this container go over light speed?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, velocity, inertial-frames, faster-than-light

Imagine a container which contains a speaker and gas at normal pressure inside.
Now imagine it moving at almost light speed (maybe c-100m/s)
if the speaker makes a sound, causing particles to move at the speed of sound.
Would the particles moving parallel to the container’s movement move faster than light? 
or is there something im missing here?

Comment: Also a duplicate of [If I run along the aisle of a bus traveling at (almost) the speed of light, can I travel faster than the speed of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7446/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the box the velocities are the velocity of sound, and in the center of mass system of box+air+speaker  masses and velocities are as known.

If the whole system moves close to  the velocity of light all the masses will  become [relativistic masses](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/mass.html), including the atoms in the air for the speaker. The calculation will show towards a limit to the velocity of light, higher than for particles at rest in the center of mass of the system, but the velocity of light will not be attained , as far as the observer seeing the box moving with velocity close to  c.

You are missing the definition of relativistic mass,that the inertial mass is not invariant to lorenz transformation, for everything that moves with velocity close to c.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :). Ive thought of the effect on the mass of particles by the motion but wasnt entirely sure about it.

Comment: Do we really need to move in relativistic mass? I would say that velocities are not additive with no dynamics consideration at all.

Comment: @Alchimista, agreed 100%.  The light speed limitation is _entirely_ kinematic, introducing dynamics is a serious distraction here.

Comment: @Alchimista I find the concept or relativistic mass useful: that the classical inertial mass increases as one approaches the velocity c  for kinematic intuition which depends on classical mechanics concepts. It is useful in calculating how much fuel is needed for a spaceship to reach relativistic velocities :). Surprisingly there are other uses, see question and answer and comments https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/398985/how-can-special-relativity-account-for-the-electron-orbital-clouds-of-stationar/399000#399000

Comment: @m4r35n357 see my comment to alchimista

Comment: Not polemics here. Perhaps it is just me that find relativistic mass quite distracting or suggesting a change within the body. As for I understand all is down to the postulates of SR in a kinematic, geometrical way. Nice to discuss with you as usual

Comment: Not polemics here. Perhaps it is just me that find relativistic mass quite distracting or suggesting a change within the body. And the OP comment to your answer seems to confirm that. As far as I understand all is down to the postulates of SR in a kinematic, geometrical way. Nice to discuss with you as usual. And @m4r35n357